# How to restrict hours to specific period in odoo calendar

Tags: odoo, odoo-14, odoo-15, odoo-16

I want to change calendar time period with some user input field.
eg.: in week calendar, I want to show only business day (8AM - 5PM) not (0AM - 12PM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that, you must update **businessHours** of fullcalendar instance

fullcalendar has **setOption()** method for option update.

Odoo instantiate fullcalendar in setup() method of **CalendarCommonRender** component.

Inherit that component and after completily mounted call **this.fc.setOption('option_name','option_value)** where you need to update fullcalendar option